# Making a Search bar Responsive

Tags: html, search, responsive-design

I am working on a new homepage at http://www.bkd.com/new-test-2.htm

We have a search bar that was previously built by a different developer who is no longer here.

I am trying to make the search bar further to the right of the screen but also still be responsive. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have tried a lot of different things and when I make the browser smaller it just jumps below the navigation. This is what I do not want to happen.

Here is the coding for the whole light grey bar:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="span-8"> 
    <a class="left"  style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; margin-left: 80px;" href="/">
    <img src="/images/common/header/logo.png"  border="0"></a> </div>
    <div style="margin-top:25px;" class="span-0 last">
    <form action="/search/">
        <input type="image" src="/images/common/search/search-icon-new.png" style="margin-left: 220px; float:left; outline:none" alt="Search">
        <input type="text" name="zoom_query" value="Search" style=" background-   image:url(/images/common/search/search-field-new.png); background-repeat: repeat-x; margin: 0; line-height:26px; height: 26px; width:200px; color:#666; background-color:#fff; border:none; outline:hidden; border-radius: 7px; float:right; padding: 0px 0px 0 10px; margin-left: 0px;" onFocus="this.value=this.value.replace(/^Search$/, '')">
    </form>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or a better way to achieve what I am trying to do. Please let me know if I need to provide any more information.

Thank you in advance!
-Marcy-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search bar is breaking down because the marker icon beside it has an unnecessary  margin of `220px`, giving the whole search div a width of 462px which causes it to break down on lower screen size.. change the following

```
<input type="image" src="/images/common/search/search-icon-new.png" style="margin-left: 220px; float:left; outline:none" alt="Search">
```

to

```
<input type="image" src="/images/common/search/search-icon-new.png" style=" float:left; outline:none" alt="Search">
```

to move the search bar to the right, apply `float:right` to the container div as follows:

```
<div style="margin-top:25px; float:right" class="span-0 last">
```

i suggest using external stylesheets instead of applying inline style, external stylesheets are likely to be cached, hence loading might become faster on consecutive visits. Also it makes your html more readable as well.